# Constructor injection with Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, simple-injector

hi i'm trying to register repository class which having IDbConnection as constructor parameter.

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public Repository(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }

    public IDbConnection Connection { get; }
}
```

i registered something like this

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WcfOperationLifestyle();
container.Register(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>), typeof(Repository<>));
container.Register(typeof(IDbConnection), typeof(Repository<User>));
    container.Register<IAuthService, AuthService>();
container.Verify();
```

what was the wrong on my code?

**Updated**
im getting exception like below

> The constructor of type Repository contains the parameter with name
>   'connection' and type IDbConnection that is not registered. Please
>   ensure IDbConnection is registered, or change the constructor of
>   Repository.

**Update 2**

> [ArgumentException: The supplied type Repository does not implement
>   IDbConnection.Parameter name: implementationType]
>   SimpleInjector.Requires.ThrowSuppliedTypeDoesNotInheritFromOrImplement(Type
>   service, Type implementation, String paramName) +63
>   SimpleInjector.Requires.ServiceIsAssignableFromImplementation(Type
>   service, Type implementation, String paramName) +47
>   SimpleInjector.Container.Register(Type serviceType, Type
>   implementationType, Lifestyle lifestyle, String serviceTypeParamName,
>   String implementationTypeParamName) +159
>   SimpleInjector.Container.Register(Type serviceType, Type
>   implementationType) +52
>   TimeTrackerService.Service.DependencyConfig..cctor() in
>   D:\TimeTracking\TimeTrackerService\libs\TimeTrackerService.Service\DependencyConfig.cs:47[TypeInitializationException:
>   The type initializer for 'TimeTrackerService.Service.DependencyConfig'
>   threw an exception.]
>   TimeTrackerService.Service.DependencyConfig.get_Container() in
>   D:\TimeTracking\TimeTrackerService\libs\TimeTrackerService.Service\DependencyConfig.cs:40
>   TimeTrackerService.WcfServiceFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) in
>   D:\TimeTracking\TimeTrackerService\TimeTrackerService\WcfServiceFactory.cs:15
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +524
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1420
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>   +641[ServiceActivationException: The service '/TrackerService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is: The type initializer for
>   'TimeTrackerService.Service.DependencyConfig' threw an exception..]
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +489035
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +174
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +350322
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +9747521

Comment: Are you getting any exception in compilation or flow is not executed as you require?

Comment: hi i updated question with exception message i'm getting

Comment: `Repository<User>` implement `IDbConnection` interface?

Comment: @Grundy no it does not

Comment: so, do you have a clas that implement `IDbConnection`? i think here `container.Register(typeof(IDbConnection), typeof(Repository<User>));` should be class that implement selected interface instead `typeof(Repository<User>)`

Comment: @Grundy IDbConnection is from `System.Data`

Comment: this is just _interface_, you need a class that implement it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93400/discussion-between-grundy-and-gayan-ranasinghe).

Comment: Which version of Simple Injector are you using? If `Repository<T>` does not implement `IDbConnection` the call to `Register(typeof(IDbConnection), typeof(Repository<User>))` will fail. And please add a stack trace to your question.

Comment: @Steven, you mean this [require](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/master/SimpleInjector.NET/Container.Registration.cs#L1184)?

Comment: @Grundy Exactly. My impression is that some code is missing from the question.

Comment: @Steven I'm using version 2.7.2 Repository<T> does not implement IDbConnection i use this to enable dapper extensions. i updated question with stack trace.

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe, so as say Steven, you get `The supplied type Repository does not implement IDbConnection.Parameter`

Comment: @Grundy yeah I did workaround as below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another way, to avoid adding own interface and implementation.
Using this override for Register method:
[`Container.Register<TService>(Func<TService> instanceCreator, Lifestyle lifestyle)`](https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/html/M_SimpleInjector_Container_Register__1_3.htm)

Something like this:

```
container.Register<IDbConnection>(() =>{ 
    var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrackerConnection"]; 
    if (con == null) 
        throw new Exception("Failed to find connection"); 

    var _provider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(con.ProviderName); 

    var connection = _provider.CreateConnection(); 
    if (connection == null) 
        throw new Exception($"Failed to create a connection using the connection string named '{con.ProviderName}' in app.config or web.config."); 

    connection.ConnectionString = con.ConnectionString; 
    return connection; 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally i came up with solution. instead of injecting `IDbConnection` i inject own interface with implementation. `IDataFactory` and `DataFactory`. this implementation returns `IDbConnection`

```
private readonly string _providerName;
private readonly DbProviderFactory _provider;
public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

public DataFactory()
{
    var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrackerConnection"];
    if (con == null)
        throw new Exception("Failed to find connection");
    ConnectionString = con.ConnectionString;
    _providerName = con.ProviderName;
    _provider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(con.ProviderName);
}
public IDbConnection Connection
{
    get
    {
        var connection = _provider.CreateConnection();
        if (connection == null)
            throw new Exception($"Failed to create a connection using the connection string named '{_providerName}' in app.config or web.config.");
        connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        return connection;
    }
}
```

then i registered

```
container.Register<IDataFactory, DataFactory>();
```

Now i inject my implementation

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public Repository(IDataFactory factory)
    {
        Factory= factory;
    }

    public IDataFactory Factory{ get; }
}
```

now when i use `Factory.Connection` it works as expected

thanks